# How to play mp3 file using Blob-key of blob store of app engine in jsp file with HTML5 audio tag?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, html5-audio, blobstore

I uploaded my 4MB mpe file in App engine blobstore. By retrieving its Blob-key, i tried to play it in jsp file using HTML 5 audio tag. But its not working . The code is given below:

```
<%@page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey" %>
<%@page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>
<%@page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="audio/mpeg3; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(request.getParameter("blob-key"));
%><%=request.getParameter("blob-key")%>

<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="<%=request.getParameter("blob-key")%>" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your audio tag's `src` attribute should point to an Url where a blob (audio stream) can be downloaded. Instead it just holds a value of the blob key (which is a random string and not an Url, so it does not point anywhere).

It's best to start reading how to [serve a blob](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob).

Basically, there isn't an universal blob-serving url, that you could just make a request to and it would serve your blob. You need to create a servlet that serves blobs (see example in the link) and then point the HTML5 audio control to it via `src="/path/to/your/blob/servlet?key=<%=request.getParameter("blob-key")%>"`.

Comment: if u have problem in above code please set response header & content typle also.res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment ;filename =en.mp3");res.setContentType("audio/mpeg3");